# Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: programming, uploading, arduino-pro-mini, ftdi

I have the following problem

I have a pro mini clone, with 328/5V. It was successfully working in my board. I pulled it out of the board, and wanted to update my software. I connected it to my FTDI, arduino was normal by this time. Power on LED was on. I stared uploading, my sketch compiled and started writing. While it was writing, my 3.5 year old daughter who approached me from behind and whom I did not see pulled the Arduino out of FTDI - "what is that nice red light?" Of course writing failed. 
Now, when I connect the arduino to FTDI, it is dead. No LEDs light up, no sync... what to do? Any chance to revive it?

Comment: Check the FTDI as well. Voltmeter could be helpful.

Comment: Just flashed another Arduino board to test - worked without problems...

Comment: Ok, then if looks like FTDI is alive and the Pro Mini is dead.

Comment: Just decided to examine the Arduino for physical damage, and that was it! Looks like she ripped Arduino off the cable so hard, that the solder holding the programming pin row was not holding! I resoldered all connector pins, and it worked now!

Comment: Tough thing. You are lucky. Cheers! Please mark the question as answered (i.e. provide your solution as an answer and accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for physical damage! Solder connection of the programming pins to the board was damaged in my case. Resoldering helped!